# How to create different EC2 instances with different tags in Ansible

Tags: ansible

The following Ansible code creates 1 EC2 instance with 1 tag

```yaml
    - ec2:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_access_key }}"
        ec2_region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        assign_public_ip: yes
        instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ aws_ami }}"
        keypair: ansible_key
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ aws_subnet_id }}"
        group_id: "{{ aws_security_group }}"
        exact_count: 1
        count_tag:
          name: first_group
        instance_tags:
          name: first_group
        wait: yes
      register: ec2
    - debug:
        var: ec2
```

What is the best way to rework this code to create 2 EC2 instances, each one with a different tag?

Comment: What have you tried and what did not work as expected? If you don't know where to start, you should probably read [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, this is OLD STUFF, so it may not work any more.  But I defined the inventory first, in `group_vars/all.yml`:

```
env_id: EE_TEST3_SLS
env_type: EE
zones:
   - zone: presentation
     servers:
     - type: rp
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: L7
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
   - zone: application
     servers:
     - type: app
       count: 2
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: sre
       count: 0
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: httpd
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: terracotta
       count: 4
       mirror_groups: 2
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: L7
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
   - zone: data
     servers:
     - type: batch
       count: 2
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: terracotta_tmc
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: terracotta
       count: 2
       mirror_groups: 1
       instance_type: m4.xlarge
     - type: oracle
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.4xlarge
     - type: marklogic
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.4xlarge
     - type: alfresco
       count: 1
       instance_type: m4.4xlarge
```

Then, the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Provision a set of instances
    ec2:
        instance_type: "{{ item.1.instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ image }}"
        region: "{{ region }}"
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnets[item.0.zone] }}"
        tenancy: "{{ tenancy }}"
        group_id: "{{ group_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
        wait: true
        instance_tags:
           EnvID: "{{ env_id }}"
           Type: "{{ item.1.type }}"
           Zone: "{{ item.0.zone }}"
        count_tag:
           EnvID: "{{ env_id }}"
           Type: "{{ item.1.type }}"
           Zone: "{{ item.0.zone }}"
        exact_count: "{{ item.1.count }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ zones }}"
      - servers
    register: ec2_results
```

The idea is that you set all the tags in the inventory, and just reference them in the task.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you'd simply want to create the same instances only replacing values `first_group` with `second_group` in the module parameters, the following (totally untested) example should put you on track.

If you need to go further, as already advised in comments, have a look at [the ansible loop documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

```yaml
    - ec2:
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_access_key }}"
        ec2_region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        assign_public_ip: yes
        instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ aws_ami }}"
        keypair: ansible_key
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ aws_subnet_id }}"
        group_id: "{{ aws_security_group }}"
        exact_count: 1
        count_tag:
          name: "{{ item }}"
        instance_tags:
          name: "{{ item }}"
        wait: yes
      register: ec2
      loop:
        - first_group
        - second_group

    - debug:
        var: ec2.results
```